# Implementing LINQ select using boost range

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm experimenting a bit with implementing a LINQ wrapper around boost::range.

However, I'm struck with select where I'm getting "An internal error has occurred in compiler".

```
template<typename R>
class linq_range
{
    R range;
public:

    linq_range(R range)
        : range(std::move(range))
    {
    }

    template<typename F>
    auto select(const F& f) const -> linq_range<decltype(std::declval<R>() | boost::adaptors::transformed(f))>
    {
        return linq_range<decltype(std::declval<R>() | boost::adaptors::transformed(f))>(this->range | boost::adaptors::transformed(f));
    }
};

template<typename R>
auto from(R& r) -> linq_range<boost::iterator_range<decltype(std::begin(r))>>
{
    return from(std::begin(r), std::end(r));
}

template<typename I>
linq_range<boost::iterator_range<I>> from(I b, I e)
{
    return linq_range<boost::iterator_range<I>>(boost::iterator_range<I>(b, e));
}
```

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Can you give the full code that actually triggers the error? Without a single instantiation it's hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by defining:

```
BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```

Comment: I know it seems a little cheesy since it was your question and all, but if this really was the answer you should accept it.